# Does Google Chrome wipe the profile data?

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, wipe

When turning off sync in Google Chrome, there's an option called "Clear bookmarks, history, passwords and more from this device".

Will this do [data erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure), so that the data is completely overwritten, or can it be restored from unallocated disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome tells your OS to delete the files. Your OS deletes the files.
That's it.

Conceivably on an encrypted SSD with Trim, then the data would eventually be wiped, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Just curious: How do you know? Is there a tool that shows what file-deletion requests the OS receives?

Comment: @root - It's just common sense.  If there is a tool that does that it would be against the rules to recommend it.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not against the rules to state *whether* a tool exists. Nor to name one as proof.